# Trying to create nested accordion from database

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp-classic, accordion

I have retrieve records from a  database in the following format

```
Week, BU, Day, details
10,   1,  Tue, 'what happened today'
10,   1,  Wed, 'and today'
10,   2,  Mon, 'What happened today'
10,   2,  Mon, 'something else happened today'
9,    1,  Mon, 'what happened today'
9,    1,  Mon, 'and this'
9,    1,  Tue, 'What happened today'
9,    1,  Wed, 'something happened today'   etc
```

I want to create a nested accordion matching this example http://jsfiddle.net/pzh20/fcjq2dd0/2/

I'm really struggling working out how to do it in classic ASP/vbscript. Obviously, a series of do loops for the, inner day, then one for the next day then one for the change of BU then one for the change of week.

Any pointers?

Regards
Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Do`/`Loop` when you can use `For`/`Next`--You don't want to keep the db object open doing this loop, second it's just faster.

You would need to iterate through your db data recording changes during the loop, so you know what the last value was and if it is now different, to write the html. So first I suggest you use [`.GetRows()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to capture the db data instead of using `do`/`loop` and keeping the db object active longer than it need be.

```vb
Set oRs = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Recordset")
oRs.Open "SELECT...", Conn
If Not oRs.EOF Then aRows = oRs.GetRows()
oRs.Close
Set oRs = Nothing
```

Once you have your `.GetRows()` array, you can loop through it as many times as you want without using db resources any longer.

So now that you have your db data in an array, you would loop through it something like this:

```vb
If IsArray(aRows) Then

  LastWeek = ""
  LastBU = ""
  LastDay = ""

  For i = 0 to uBound(aRows,2)

    ThisWeek = aRows(0,i)
    If ThisWeek <> LastWeek Then 
       LastWeek = ThisWeek
       Response.Write "<div class=week>"
    End If

    'Do the same for BU and Day here    

    'Then you can write your details:
    Response.Write "<div class=details>" & aRows(3,i) & "</div>"


    'Then close your parent div
    'Week div
    If i = uBound(aRows,2) Then 
      Response.Write "</div>"
    Else
      If aRows(0,i+1) <> ThisWeek Then Response.Write "</div>"
    End If
    'do the same for bu and day here

  Next

End If
```

NOTE: Make sure you're sorting it in your SQL statement (ie `ORDER BY Week,BU,Day`) the way you want it displayed or it may be out of order.

Comment: Good answer, only thing I would say is use `If Not oRS.EOF Then` instead of `.RecordCount > 0` as you will come a cropper when using different cursor types and your `.RecordCount` returns `-1`.

Comment: Sometimes I get problems using `Not oRs.EOF`, but I updated it.

Comment: With quite a lot of extra checking for the ubound(aRows) using your basic principal worked. Thanks for this.

Pete

Comment: @PeteHarrison Extra checking? If you have checked `IsArray()` store the `Ubound()` once then you don't need to keep checking it. Not sure what you mean by a lot of extra checking, I guarantee this method is far more efficient then looping the `ADODB.Recordset`.

Comment: @ZeeTee You could use [The Magical `Mod()` Function](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19315/The-Magical-Mod-Function.htm) to workout when to write `</div>`, awesome for that type of thing `i + 1 Mod NumOfWeekDays = 0`